# How can I find some pieces of the genome of a microorganism?

Tags: bioinformatics

I have figured out how to download the fasta of the genomes of microorganisms, for example the botulism bacteria and the spirulina algae. However, I want to find a fasta file for some significant extraction of those genomes - say, some important gene, some mutation, some protein that occurs in a microorganisms genome. What should I look for, and how can I find it in genbank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use already available tools to extract information from available database. For finding specific genes, use [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/). For protein, use [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/). There are lot more tools. Just explore [NCBI](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), [EMBL](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/services) or [DDBJ](http://www.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/searches-e.html) sites. All information is self explanatory. 
If you want specialized information for specific organism, you can use specialized database ( like [Flybase](http://flybase.org/) for flies, [SGD](http://www.yeastgenome.org/) for common yeast, [EnsemblBacteria](http://bacteria.ensembl.org/index.html) for bacteria and archaea or [HGMD](http://www.hgmd.cf.ac.uk/ac/index.php) for human mutations. Best way is to search in Google. You will get everything you want :D

Comment: I found these websites a bit daunting. I don't know what genes to look for - I don't know the names of any genes in, say, arthrospira. I have clicked on some genes but I get very complicated diagrams, not fasta files.

Comment: You should have little idea about what you want, else you will be lost in sequences and genes. You can look at [Gene Ontology](http://geneontology.org/) database. Here you can search genes and proteins with annotated functions. I guess that is what you want. However this will give you only reported (or annotated) genes/proteins. You can't find novel genes there. You need proper bioinformatics study to find such genes (like searching through various domains and validating them from literature)

Comment: I used GO to find the name of a mycoplasma protein, and I found mycoplasma page on NCBI: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/1028. I can't figure out how to get the FASTA from that page - do you know?

Comment: There was [direct link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/genomes/1028) on that page. Click on whatever sequence you want (click on replicons column )

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have found the Genome entry of your favourite genomes in Genbank and got the FastA.

Dexter is completely right, you can just search your genes in the databases and filter them for your genomes of interest.

Another possibility is to get the GenBank-formated file "GenBank (full)", instead of the FastA, then use a Genome Browser (for example [Artemis](http://www.sanger.ac.uk/resources/software/artemis/)) which allows you to search for genes/proteins in a genome and save them as separate FastA files.

Generally it is a good thing to get the GenBank format file for an organism you are interested in, as you can extract the complete genome sequence as FastA easily, but also keep all the other information you might need later.